# alter varchar field to super returns " ERROR: target data type "super" is not supported"

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a varchar field in super/json format:

```
select detail
from mytable
limit 1;

{"child_category":"organize","gallery_id":"123456","detail":"[\"789876"]"}
```

I know that detail is currently varchar because inspecting the table in my client shows it as `varchar(32768)`

I want alter this field to be super:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN detail TYPE super;
```

Returns:

```
[0A000] ERROR: target data type "super" is not supported
```

How can I cast the detail field as a super field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html
with alter column you can only change varchar size.

As a suggestion, you can add new temp column, drop first, and rename temp column

```sql
alter table mytable add column temp_super super;
update mytable set temp_super = json_parse(detail);
alter table mytable drop column detail;
alter table mytable rename column temp_super to detail;
```